# get current object in django filter orm

Tags: python, django, django-models, filter, django-orm

It may be a basic question but please bear with me. How to get the current object in the ORM query.

```
 x = 'abc'
 sample = Sample.objects.filter( x__in = sample_obj.x_list )
```

`sample_obj` refers to all the objects of `Sample`. Here Sample is a model having x_list:

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    x_list = ListTextField(
        base_field=models.CharField(max_length=20),
        size=10, max_length=(10 * 11))
```

So basically i want to filter, if the list field in model has a particular value.
**Edit** : I would clarify my question further : Let there be 3 `Sample` objects, i want to check if `x` in any of the Sample object's `x_list`. And save those objects in variable `sample`. Let `x_list` be a list of strings.

Comment: What do you mean with the *current* object?

Comment: What if there are multiple objects that match? Or none at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [__contains](http://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/list_fields.html#contains) lookup instead of `__in`:

samples = Sample.objects.filter(x_list__contains=x)

Comment: What if `x` is also a list, and i want exact match. i.e. if all the items in `x` matches items in `x_list` ?

Comment: I think you can just use `=` operator. like `Sample.objects.filter(x_list=x)`

Comment: I meant `x_list` can have other items, but all items in `x` should be in `x_list`.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a built-in query for that but you can query it like this: `Sample.objects.filter(**{"x_list__contains": value for value in x})`